# Manipulate FOR command variables?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, variables

It works.

```
:: %%a is output of FOR loop in batch:  
set _string=%%a  
:: First two chars:  
set "_two=!_string:~0,2!"
```

I would like to get the two characters by operating directly on %%a,
i.e. without creating the intermediate variable _string.
Possible?

Comment: The `FOR` variable only works within the scope of the `FOR` command. You have no `FOR` command in your code. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And also read, [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: To answer your question. You can only do string manipulation on Environmental Variables. Meta-Variables from the FOR command or command line arguments cannot be manipulated directly.

Comment: @Squashman, you saw, upon reconsideration, that my question is a good question,
then answered according, for which I thank you.  Exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible without creating an intermediate variable, but without putting an actual task to your request, the solution may not be as `EZ` as the examples below, *which utilise `PowerShell`*:

Batch file example:

```bat
@For %%A In ("ezrine") Do @PowerShell "('%%A').SubString(0,2)"
@Pause
```

…and at the command prompt:

```bat
For %A In ("ezrine") Do @PowerShell "('%A').SubString(0,2)"
```

You can even do other things, *like forcing upper case output*:

```bat
@For %%A In ("ezrine") Do @PowerShell "('%%A').SubString(0,2).ToUpper()"
@Pause
```

Comment: Without knowing the environment the batch runs in, I*d include `-NoP -C` for `-NoProfile -Command`. In higher PowerShell versions (admittedly  PowerShell 6 core) the positional parameter 0 changes from -Command to -File.

Comment: @LotPings, I would probably use `-NoP` too, but the question was about the possibility so I provided only what was necessary to prove it possible. Had the OP have provided more information, I would have considered doing so too!

Comment: @Compo, a great bonus to know that I can use PS commands in Batch shell.
And I did apply your example to my script.

Comment: @displayname, it would be appreciated were you to mark my answer as accepted, _by clicking on the large check mark to its left_.

Comment: Ah, so that's how it works.  Ok, did it.

Is there a way to give some kinda credit to Squashman?

Comment: @displayname, there isn't, but like myself, he's not a point chaser. Marking the answer as accepted is more important for the site and future visitors, _it adds confidence_, upvoting a comment, by clicking on the upward arrow to its left, should be sufficient to show it's worth to those future readers.